# Which formula for elastic collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, elasticity

When researching a bit about elastic collisions, I've been confused about how many different ways there are to do this. I've seen multiple methods, some of which are extremely complex (using sine and cosine) and some which are more simple.

For example, this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/345863/10350056) provides a simple solution, while this [tutplus article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/playing-around-with-elastic-collisions--active-7472) uses a more complex solution.

I'm trying to make a simple simulation which there are balls that bouncing around borders and other balls. What formula should I use and what are the differences between them?

Comment: Complexity of the computation will increase if both the colliding objects are moving and-or if they have different masses and-or sizes.

Comment: The stackoverflow one seems simple because ut uses the right objects for the job: vectors.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for or trying calculate?

Comment: @TechDroid I'm wondering why there are different methods of calculating elastic collisions, why they differ, and which one would be the best to use.

Comment: The velocity component of the formula of momentum is a vector, the sine and cosine involved is meant to calculate the velocity vector component of the masses involved parallel to each other. You don't get the sines and cosines only when the collision is head on aligned. Elastic collision conserves kinetic energy too, so you'll have to to calculatr for final kinetic energy if required.

Comment: @TechDroid So if I am simulating 2D balls bouncing at each other with at random angles with random velocities, it is recommended to us cosine and sine?

Comment: It's not a recommendation, you'll have to, there are no two way about it. And balls are spheres, which is 3D, I suppose you mean circles on a plane kind of thing.

Comment: @TechDroid Does that mean that the StackOverflow answer (above) is wrong?

Comment: Loosely speaking, we can say a ball on 2D plane is a ball, but I just couldn't help it but clarify an actual ball being spherical.

Comment: @Sarah If you define a local coordinate system that is fixed to the center of mass of the two balls, you don't need sines and cosines. The $x$ and $y$ componsnts of velocity after the collision are just $-e \times$ the components before the collision, where $e$ is the coefficient of restitution ($=1$ for perfectly elastic collision) and you don';t need to *rotate* the coordinate system, so you don't need sines and cosines. The tutplus tutorial doesn't use that fact, it rotates the local coordinates so the collision is always along the local $x$ axis.

Comment: @TechDroid No, you don't need to use sines and cosines. See my previous comment. (And it doesn't matter whether the model is 2D or 3D either).

Comment: @Alephzero, well that's new, I'll investigate further, thanks for pointing out the flaw, great job.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I'm working to test both out and I'll see if there's any difference.

Comment: I miss the days where functions using sines and cosines was considered to be "extremely complex"

Answer (score -1):

After testing both out, it seems that they both behave the same in the case where the masses are the same.